# How get raw data from header and send to view ? php qr code

Tags: php

I try to build site with collect some links and then i would like generate to each link small QR code. I use php QR Code and when i try generate basic code like this

```
public function testAction{
    QRcode::png('PHP QR Code :)');
}
```

i se white site with empty QR code. 
But when i disable view and render

```
public function testAction{
    $this->_helper->layout()->disableLayout();
    $this->_helper->viewRenderer->setNoRender(true);
   QRcode::png('PHP QR Code :)');
}
```

I see my QR code but only this without my view.

How can i send this QR code to view without write this code to file ?

Comment: You'll want to generate the QR code in a separate file. In your view file, add an image sourced to the QR code file with some GET parameters that tell the QR code file what to generate in the QR code.

Comment: Can i do this without write qr code to file ?

Comment: Yes. [Read the Usage section](http://phpqrcode.sourceforge.net/index.php)

Comment: Yes i saw this section but i have an idea. I can create file for a moment and convert on base64 delete file and send base64 as show file ? hmmm make sense ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To elaborate on my comments above, you can create a separate php file that does nothing but generate the QR code based off of $_GET parameters you send to it in the URL.

```
<?php // qrcode.php
    QRcode::png($_GET['parameter']);
```

If you view `qrcode.php?parameter=Hello%20World` you will get a QR code for `Hello World`

If you create an image sourced to qrcode.php, it will output that generated QR code:

```
<img src="qrcode.php?parameter=Hello%20World" />
```

without creating a qr code image file.